# How do I get the total of one column based on all cells in another column being over 0

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a column showing hourly rate, and another column showing the number of hours at that rate. I want to then get a total of the income, only if the hourly rate is above 0 (i.e. the session took place).

[image]

Comment: `SUMIF` maybe??

Comment: Hmm.` =A1 * B1` will return zero if one of the two cells has a value that evaluates to zero. If A1 contains $30 (sorry, I don't have a Sterling sign), it presumably contains a number. If B1 contains "1.00", meaning a text string, that will evaluate to zero. If you want the numeric text string to be evaluated to a number use`=A1*Val(B1)`. If you need to calculate the total of each row and all rows you should look for an array formula.

Comment: All the value to your image are above `0 (Zero)`. Use `Sumproduct()` then.

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT` returns the correct result even if any of the values is zero

Answer (score 1):

Sumproduct will work as mentioned in the comments

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A8,B1:B8)
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(B:B>0; A:A; )))
```